# Script SQL con columna '-1'

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tengo este script SQL:

```
create view transactview as (
 select SUM(quantity) as venta,tag,shift_id,pump,nozzle from transactions 
 where tag in (100,200,300,400) group by tag,shift_id,pump,nozzle
 union select SUM(quantity) as venta,'-1',shift_id,pump,nozzle from transactions
 where tag not in (100,200,300,400) group by shift_id,pump,nozzle )
```

Y no entiendo la función de la columna '-1' en el segundo "Select" o por que esta ahí.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El valor `-1` es un valor por defecto asignado como segunda columna del segundo SELECT.

Esta es tu consulta *un poco mas organizada*:

```
create view transactview as
(
   select SUM(quantity) as venta, tag, shift_id, pump, nozzle 
   from transactions 
   where tag in (100,200,300,400)
   group by tag,shift_id,pump,nozzle
   union 
   select SUM(quantity) as venta, '-1', shift_id, pump, nozzle 
   from transactions
   where tag not in (100,200,300,400)
   group by shift_id,pump,nozzle
)
```

En tu caso, sería el valor asignado a la columna `tag`.

Comment: y por que no simplemente se coloco tag?

Comment: @CamiloMedina Bueno, eso depende de cuáles son los valores disponibles para `tag` en tu tabla

Comment: Es probable que el requerimiento fuera, en la Interfaz de Usuario, poder agrupar, o al menos identificar todos los tags restantes bajo uno solo, probablemente algo como _otros tags_, o similares.